# SoapUi load-testing

Tags: soapui, load-testing

Is it possible to run a load test e.g. simple strategy in 20 threads and each thread have to run the setup script again after the test case ends?

Answer (score 0):

http://www.soapui.org/load-testing/creating-and-running-loadtests.html

please go through the above tutorial, simple strategy can run using 20 threads with some delay.